# Why firebase map Integer key is throwing a ClassCastException

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So, in my database I have a map of type

When I fetch it I get the value of the key (integer) and the string value

```
 val time = infoSnapshot.get("opentimes") as Map<Int, String>
        for (entries in time.entries) {
            myList.add(OpenTime(entries.key, entries.value))
        }
```

Now, when I get this I get this error

[image]

```
java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

But that in my database is not represented as a String, the key is represented by a number

I dont know why my entry keys are getting this problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I dont know if this is a Firebase problem but I have to change my HashMap to `<String,String>` and parse that Integer value from firebase that is taken as String to int

```
val time = infoSnapshot.get("opentimes") as Map<String, String>
```

Comment: The keys in Firestore are always Strings and not numbers.